# How to render component from method of another component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a form which contains selector input, and this form is in pop-up window. Now my selector not displayed, because it renders after the main window loaded. How can I make the component which renders my selector (renderPositions), render it from method showPopup() (after the pop-up window appears)? Thanks in advance.

```
var usersControllerApi = Vue.resource('./users_controller/all{/id}')
var positionsControllerApi = Vue.resource('./positions_controller/all{/id}')

Vue.component('users',  {
props: ['listOfUsers'],
template: '<tbody>' +
    '<tr v-for="user in listOfUsers" >' +
    '<td class="first_column">{{user.login}}</td>' +
    '<td>{{user.fullName}}</td>' +
    '<td>{{user.position.positionDescription}}</td>' +
    '<td>{{user.active ? "Да" : "Нет"}} </td>' +
    '<td>{{user.createDate}}</td>' +
    '<td>{{user.lastUpdateDate}}</td>' +
    '<td class="seven_column"><button>Изменить</button></td>' +
    '<td class="eight_column"><button>Удалить</button></td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</tbody>',
created: function () {
    usersControllerApi.get().then(result => result.json().then(data => data.forEach(user => {
            this.listOfUsers.push(user)
        }
    )))
}
});

Vue.component('positions', {
props: ['listOfPositions'],
template: '<select class="form_input" id="positionsselector">' +
    '<option v-for="position in listOfPositions" v-bind:value="position.positionDescription">{{position.positionDescription}}</option>' +
    '</select>',
created: function () {
    positionsControllerApi.get().then(result => result.json().then(data => data.forEach(pos => {
            this.listOfPositions.push(pos)
        }
    )))
}
});

var renderUser = new Vue({
el: '#tableBody',
template: '<users :listOfUsers="listOfUsers" />',
data: {
    listOfUsers: []
}
});


var renderPositions = new Vue({
el: '#positionsselector',
template: '<positions :listOfPositions="listOfPositions"/>',
data: {
    listOfPositions: []
}
});

var createButtonScope = new Vue({
el: '#createButtonScope',
data: {
    isPopupVisible: false,
    login_input:'',
    password_input:'',
    repassword_input:'',
    surname_input:'',
    name_input:'',

},
methods: {
    showPopup() {
        this.isPopupVisible = true;

    },
    closeModalWindow() {
        this.isPopupVisible = false;
    },
    validate() {
    }
}
})


var comp = Vue.component('add-popup', {
props: {
    header_title: '',
    button_1_name: '',
    button_2_name: ''
},
template: '            <div id="popup_window">\n' +
    '                <div class="Dialog">\n' +
    '                    <div class="Dialog_overlay">\n' +
    '                        <div class="Dialog_content">\n' +
    '                            <div class="Dialog_header">\n' +
    '                                <span class="modal_header_text">{{header_title}}</span>\n' +
    '                                <span><i class="material-icons" @click="closePopup">close</i></span>\n' +
    '                            </div>\n' +
    '                            <div class="Dialog_body">\n' +
    '                                <slot></slot>\n' +
    '                            </div>\n' +
    '                            <div class="Dialog_footer">\n' +
    '                                <div class="modal_button_1_container">\n' +
    '                                    <button class="modal_button_1" @click="validate_form">Создать</button>\n' +
    '                                </div>\n' +
    '                                <div class="modal_button_2_container">\n' +
    '                                    <button class="modal_button_2" @click="closePopup">Отмена</button>\n' +
    '                                </div>\n' +
    '                            </div>\n' +
    '                        </div>\n' +
    '                    </div>\n' +
    '                </div>\n' +
    '            </div>',
methods: {
    closePopup() {
        this.$emit('close_popup') элементу
    },
    validate_form() {
        this.$emit('validate')элементу
    }
},
data: function () {
    return {
    }
}
});
```

Comment: v-if with isPopupVisible would be enough

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work whatever.
Here is the html code snippet into which I inject the dropdown component.
It is in the createButtonScope scope
 <select class="form_input" id="positionsselector" v-if="isPopupVisible"></select>
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you create two Vue objects? How do they related to each other?

Comment: createButtonScope -  handles appearing of popup window;
renderPositions - renders dropdown list to this popup window.

Comment: Usually you have only one Vue instance per an app. All components should be registered by Vue.component or in the components section of other components (is case of child components).

Comment: I edited starttopic, so  there now all the code is completely. Please tell me how to organize it correctly so that dropdown list displayed in popup window

Comment: can you create a simplified example in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Badboy135/tn8xsf9m/20 
I was able to localize the problem So in JS part (lines 29-36), if i hardcode pushing to positions array some positions, everything is ok, positions are displayed in droplist, but if i get data from server, I receive data (console.log(pos.positionDescription) prints positions in console), but they do not display in droplist. Moreover, if you move the html code with <selector> from the pop-up window (from line 81) to the body of main window (for example to line 106), data from the server is displayed well.

Comment: First of all you have to remain only one Vue instance, all other ones should be turned into components and included in this Vue instance.

Comment: Ok, thank U, I will follow your advice

Comment: I remained one Vue instance, as U said, and it worked! Thank U very much!